# Why a method testing with mockito run (mock ok) but another method in the same class no mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I have a Spring Boot Application in Java and I want to test the controller class. The controller class use a service class. I created a listPerson in the test, I mocked the service class and I use the when(.getAPerson).thenReturn(listPersons) and it's ok I have the list of persons created in my test. If I use anotherMethod in the same class the mock not working and I have a empty list.

My Controller is :

```
// get a person
    @GetMapping(value = "person/{firstNamelastName}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Persons>> getAPerson(@PathVariable String firstNamelastName, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        String elemjson = "persons";
        List<Persons> listP = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            listP = repositorySafetyNetInterface.getAPerson(firstNamelastName, elemjson);
            if (listP.isEmpty()) {
                response.setStatus(204);
                messagelogger = "No Content. The person does not exist."
                        + loggerApiNewSafetyNet.loggerInfo(request, response, firstNamelastName);
                LOGGER.info(messagelogger);
                return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatus()).build();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response.setStatus(404);
            return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatus()).build();
        } catch (NullPointerException nulle) {
            response.setStatus(404);
            return null;
        }

        messagelogger = "OK" + loggerApiNewSafetyNet.loggerInfo(request, response, firstNamelastName);
        LOGGER.info(messagelogger);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(listP, HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
    }
```

// add a person
@PostMapping(value = "/person")
public ResponseEntity addPerson(@RequestBody Persons person, HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) {

```
    List<Persons> listP = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        listP = repositoryElementJson.getPersons("persons");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listP = repositorySafetyNetInterface.postPerson(person);

    if (listP.isEmpty()) {
        response.setStatus(404);
        messagelogger = "No persons added. " + RESPONSSTATUS + response.getStatus() + ":"
                + loggerApiNewSafetyNet.loggerInfo(request, response, "");
        LOGGER.info(messagelogger);
        return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatus()).build();
    }

    response.setStatus(201);
    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{firstName+lastName}")
            .buildAndExpand(person.getFirstName() + person.getLastName()).toUri();
    messagelogger = "A new person is added successful. The URL is : " + location;
    LOGGER.info(messagelogger);
    messagelogger = "Created " + loggerApiNewSafetyNet.loggerInfo(request, response, "");
    LOGGER.info(messagelogger);
    // c'est quoi la différence entre les 2 lignes suivantes created(location).build
    // et
    // https.valuesOf(response.getstatus):
    return new ResponseEntity<>(person, HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
}
```

My class service :

```
@Override
public List<Persons> getAPerson(String firstNamelastName, String elemjson) throws IOException {
    List<Persons> listPersons = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Persons> listP = listPersons;
    listPersons = getListsElementsJsonRepository.getPersons(elemjson); // here we have a list of objects Persons
                                                                       // from json

    for (Persons element : listPersons) {
        if ((element.getFirstName().trim() + element.getLastName().trim()).equalsIgnoreCase(firstNamelastName)) {
            listP.add(element);
        }
    }
    LOGGER.debug("Get the person is ok.");
    return listP;
}

@Override
public List<Persons> postPerson(Persons person) {

    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug(loggerApiNewSafetyNet.loggerDebug(person.toString()));
    }

    // read the Json File
    List<Persons> listPersons;
    listPersons = createListPersons();

    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        messageLogger = "The persons are: " + listPersons;
        LOGGER.debug(messageLogger);
    }

    // verify if the persons is exist in the persons if not = add
    boolean findperson = false;
    for (Persons element : listPersons) {
        if ((element.getFirstName() + element.getLastName())
                .equals(person.getFirstName() + person.getLastName())) {
            findperson = true;

            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("This person is already in the list.");
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!findperson) {
        Boolean filecreated = false;
        // add the persons if find_persons is false
        listPersons.add(person); // add the body

        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            messageLogger = "The person is added in the list: " + listPersons;
            LOGGER.debug(messageLogger);
        }

        // create the new file json
        // create list fire stations
        List<Firestations> listFirestations;
        listFirestations = createListFirestations();
        // create list medical records
        List<Medicalrecords> listMedicalrecords;
        listMedicalrecords = createListMedicalrecords();
        newFileJson.createNewFileJson(listPersons, listFirestations, listMedicalrecords, person.toString());
        filecreated = newFileJson.isFileCreated();
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(filecreated)) { // return the person from file
            List<Persons> listP;
            listP = verifyIfTheNewPersonInTheFile(person);
            return listP;
        }
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

And my test :

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = NewSafetyAlertController.class)
public class NewSafetyAlertControllerTests {

    // Récupération de notre logger.
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(NewSafetyAlertControllerTests.class);

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private SafetyNetInterface safetyNetServiceInterface;


  @Test
    void testAddPerson() throws Exception {
        String firstName = "TEST999_FirstName";
        String lastName = "TEST999_LastName";
        String elemjson = "persons";
        List<Persons> listPersons;
        Persons person;
        person = createPerson(firstName, lastName);
        listPersons = createListPersonsTest(firstName, lastName, person);

        String body = "{\r\n" + "\"firstName\": \"" + firstName + "\",\r\n" + "\"lastName\": \"" + lastName
                + "\",\r\n" + "\"address\": \"1509 Culver St\",\r\n" + "\"city\": \"Culver\",\r\n"
                + "\"zip\": \"97451\",\r\n" + "\"phone\": \"841-874-6512\",\r\n" + "\"email\": \"jaboyd@email.com\"\r\n"
                + "}";
        when(safetyNetServiceInterface.postPerson(person)).thenReturn(listPersons);
        when(safetyNetServiceInterface.getAPerson(firstName + lastName, elemjson)).thenReturn(listPersons);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/person").content(body).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().is(201));

    }
```

The test is wrong because Expected 201 but was 404.

I use the 2 when...thenReturn because I want see you that the method getAPerson() running but the method addPerson not working.

I don't undestand the mock is ok because the mock run to method getAPerson but it's not orking to the method addPerson.

Thnak you very much
Claudiu

Comment: You ignore exceptions and return a 404. Log these exceptions and see what is happening.

Comment: Use your debugger to step through the controller.  This should tell you what has and hasn't been mocked, as well as exactly what gets executed and why.  Throwing away exceptions is generally a bad thing to do - stack traces can tell you so much about what went wrong.  And returning a 404 response to mean "something went wrong" is just plain incorrect.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the mock :( I used the debbugger : so : If this line :when(safetyNetServiceInterface.postPerson(person)).thenReturn(listPersons); in debugger I have safetyNetServiceInterface.postPerson(person)
LinkedList@107 size=0 If line after safetyNetServiceInterface.postPerson(person)
ArrayList@65 size=1 and listPersons is "[Persons{firstName='TEST999_FirstName', lastName='TEST999_LastName', address='TEST999_address', city='city', zip='zip', phone='phone', email='email'}]" but :

Comment: ...but when I arrive in controller and I tet listPersons.toString() I have the message  listPersons.toString()
"[]" so the list is Empty

Comment: why the list is empty ?

Comment: Sorry. I added my controller //post a person So when I make debugg afert the line : listP = repositoryElementJson.getPersons("persons"); I have my listPersons - so the mock is ok but after the line listP = repositorySafetyNetInterface.postPerson(person); my listP is empty

Comment: Hi&Welcome! Does `Person` have `equals/hashCode` methods? Another approach: `when(safetyNetServiceInterface.postPerson(any(Person.class)...` I think here is the problem/mockito can't match the argument;)

Comment: So `any(Person.class)` instead of (concrete) `person`...but better: correct/consistent `equals/hashCode`! ...then mockito can also match `person` (based on these two methods evaluating to `true`)

Comment: Hi ! thank you very much ! you are wonderfull on this site ! Thank you #tgdavies,   #Dawood ibn Kareem

Comment: Thank you @xerx593 ! it's ok now. when(safetyNetServiceInterface.postPerson(any(Person.class) works very good ! Thank you very much to you

Comment: So any(Person.class) it's ok. but I don't undersand why equals/hachCode should works too ? what is the connection between when...by mockito and equals/hashCode ?

Comment: I genereted the equals and hashCode into class Persons, but does not works.